# Not able to execute Silk4J test scripts in Mozilla Firefox browser, Can anybody help me out?

Tags: firefox, silktest

I am using Silk4J tool for automating a web application.I have recorded actions from IE browser and I want to execute the generated script in Mozilla Firefox browser but not able to execute the same.Firefox browser gets opened but no further actions are performed and hence the script is failing.Can anybody help me in this scenario?

Comment: What error does Silk4J show? Does it open the base URL? Does it fail to recognize any object? What are the results if you run the same test on IE?

Comment: What version of Firefox and SIlk4J are you using? Silk4J only got support for Firefox 35 and later as of Silk Test 16 Hotfix 2.

Comment: @Johnbo- Thanks for the reply. When I played back the script then Mozilla Firefox browser get opened but no further actions were played back which were recorded and when I run the same tests on IE browser then those were executed successfully.The error was displayed that your browser version is not supported so I have downgraded the FF version to 35 but still it was not executed.

Comment: @Andy - Hi , i am using FF version 35 and Silk4J version is 16.0

Comment: @Johnbo- Error: Time out expired after launching application. The requested object '//BrowserApplication[@browsertype='Firefox']' was not found within the timeout of 30 seconds this error is displayed

Comment: If you upgrade to Hotfix 2, then it should work. Older versions of Silk Test don't support FF 35.

Comment: @Andy --I have executed the script in FF 34 and it get executed successfully..I will also try to execute in FF 35 by upgrading Hotfix 2..Thank you so much for your help..Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to Silk Test 16 HF2. Older versions of Silk Test don't support FF35+.

Comment: Also note that this update will make your Firefox browser to ask you to install SilkTestAddOn 16.0.2 extension. You must accept the installation so any further version of Firefox is correctly recognized by Silk Test.